What does the ALT key do in the Windows calculator app?
Whenever I press the ALT key in the Windows calculator I see two symbols appear, an 'H' on the left and an 'I' on the right side (see screenshot). When I press the ALT again they disappear. While the two symbols are displayed the calculator seems to be in some other mode as some keys don't work anymore.
It's annoying me very much as I seem to trigger this mode quite often due to task switching to the calculator with ALT-TAB. Because the calculator works differently when this is active it usually messes up my calculations (e.g. because the decimal point does not work anymore).


I am pretty sure this feature is an accessibility feature. It might be possible to disable it, if you disable the accessibility features, but it should not be happening when your simply pressing a keyboard shortcut that uses the ALT key.

It's just the accelerator shortcut key like in the standard menu. In interfaces without a menu bar like the ribbon or the modern UWP GUI the classic Alt menu shortcut still works but the accelerator key will now be displayed over the object to be clicked


This seems to be it. I've searched through the accessibility settings to find an option to disable this behavior but couldn't find it. So I've reported it as a bug on GitHub and see what happens.

The letters show the keyboard shortcuts to access these buttons.
alt-h will open the menu, and alt-i will show the history.
